# Change Titanium Active Tab Highlight Color

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, titanium

How do you change the blue highlight color of a tab that is selected / active in Titanium? Is it possible to define an active state icon for selected tabs?

Comment: From a quick G search I see that you would need to create your own custom module to do this outside of Titanium with the SDK. Unless the Appcelerator crew plans on doing that it's not currently available.

Comment: i think it is even more complex than that, I think this is an iOS issue not appcelerator.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I have come up with a solution, I am going to abandon tabs completely and simply use buttons in a view, similar to tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add elements to the tab group itself. Then, when a tab gains focus, you can display an image over top of it.

This is necessary because (as mentioned in the comments above), iOS doesn't let us customize the colors or highlight style of tabs.

Below is a sample for how you could achieve this. You could do something a little less involved if all you want is the selected image to be different.

Hope this helps! -Dawson

```
/**
 * Override a tab group's tab bar on iOS.
 *
 * NOTE: Call this function on a tabGroup AFTER you have added all of your tabs to it! We'll look at the tabs that exist
 * to generate the overriding tab bar view. If your tabs change, call this function again and we'll update the display.
 *
 * @param tabGroup The tab group to override
 * @param backgroundOptions The options for the background view; use properties like backgroundColor, or backgroundImage.
 * @param selectedOptions The options for a selected tab button.
 * @param deselectedOptions The options for a deselected tab button.
 */
function overrideTabs(tabGroup, backgroundOptions, selectedOptions, deselectedOptions) {

    // are we restyling the tab groups?
    if (tabGroup.overrideTabs) {
        tabGroup.remove(tabGroup.overrideTabs);
    }

    // a bunch of our options need to default to 0 for everything to position correctly; we'll do it en mass:
    deselectedOptions.top = deselectedOptions.bottom = selectedOptions.top = selectedOptions.bottom = backgroundOptions.left
            = backgroundOptions.right = backgroundOptions.bottom = 0;

    // create the overriding tab bar using the passed in background options
    backgroundOptions.height = 50;
    var background = Ti.UI.createView(backgroundOptions);

    // and create our individual tab buttons
    var activeTab = null, increment = 100 / tabGroup.tabs.length;
    deselectedOptions.width = selectedOptions.width = String(increment) + '%';
    for (var i = 0, l = tabGroup.tabs.length; i < l; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            var tab = tabGroup.tabs[i];
            selectedOptions.left = deselectedOptions.left = String(increment * i) + '%';

            // set the title of the button to be the title of the tab
            selectedOptions.title = deselectedOptions.title = tab.title;

            tab.selected = Ti.UI.createButton(selectedOptions);
            tab.deselected = Ti.UI.createButton(deselectedOptions);
            tab.deselected.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (activeTab) {
                    activeTab.selected.visible = false;
                }
                tab.selected.visible = true;
                activeTab = tab;
                tabGroup.setActiveTab(i);
            });
            tab.selected.visible = false;
            background.add(tab.deselected);
            background.add(tab.selected);
        })(i);
    }

    tabGroup.add(background);
    tabGroup.overrideTabs = background;

    // "click" the first tab to get things started
    tabGroup.tabs[0].deselected.fireEvent('click');
}

/*
 The rest is a typical new project -- a tab group with three tabs.
 */

var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();
tabGroup.addTab(Ti.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Tab 1',
    window: Ti.UI.createWindow({ title: 'Tab 1', backgroundColor: '#fff' })
}));
tabGroup.addTab(Ti.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Tab 2',
    window: Ti.UI.createWindow({ title: 'Tab 2', backgroundColor: '#fff' })
}));
tabGroup.addTab(Ti.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Tab 3',
    window: Ti.UI.createWindow({ title: 'Tab 3', backgroundColor: '#fff' })
}));

/*
 Now call our overrideTabs function!
 */
overrideTabs(
    tabGroup,
    { backgroundColor: '#f00' },
    { backgroundColor: '#999', color: '#000', style: 0 },
    { backgroundColor: '#333', color: '#888', style: 0 }
);

tabGroup.open();
```

(Taken from my original Gist available here: https://gist.github.com/853935)

Answer (score 2):

The Ideal Solution is to use:

```
Ti.UI.createTab({
    icon: '/images/inactive_icon.png',
    activeIcon: '/images/active_icon.png',
});
```

Needs Ti SDK 3.1.0